# Are html::before and html::after valid? (and similar for head)

Tags: html, css

Out of curiosity, I wondered what the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements looked like when applied to `html` and `head`:

```css
html { background-color: lightblue; }
head { background-color: orange; display: block; }
body { background-color: lightgreen; }
html::before { content: "html::before"; }
head::before { content: "head::before"; }
body::before { content: "body::before"; }
html::after { content: "html::after"; }
head::after { content: "head::after"; }
body::after { content: "body::after"; }
::before, ::after { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<h1>This is some text.</h1>
<p>This is some text.</p>
```

Is this even valid? Are there any nuances to be aware of if doing this?

(Things also get interesting if you set both `body` and `head` to `display: inline-block`)

Comment: Well you put those css in a validator and it says it is valid, the html looks simple enough so it's probably valid but I don't see anyone doing this on a rgular basis

Comment: @Huangism I know it is syntactically valid, but there is more than just syntax in validity.

Comment: Make a page and run it through the validator to see what it says. If it says it is valid then it is. But again, anyone with common sense would probably not do this. Maybe it is something that the validator currently does not check.